# Informatica expression Versus sequence generator

Tags: sequence, informatica

In informatica if we can generate sequence numbers using expression transformation then why do we need sequence generator transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Sequence Generator transformation has certain features which are difficult if not impossible to implement using expression transformation. For example, a single Sequence Generator transformation can be connected to multiple target instances and will still generate unique sequence across the targets. Also, sequence generator can persist values without separate mapping variables, and a reusable sequence generator can be used in multiple mappings to generate unique sequences across mappings.